# WHERE or HAVING for MYSQL month() queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a report that shows data for the selected month. My MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT Count(images.image_url)             AS num_images, 
       ( Day(Date(timestamp)) )            AS tday, 
       Month(Date(transactions.timestamp)) AS month, 
       transactions.sr_no 
FROM   bni_pixcapp_client_details AS transactions 
       INNER JOIN bni_pixcapp_image_urls AS images 
               ON images.sr_no = transactions.sr_no 
WHERE  Month(Date(transactions.timestamp)) = 4 
       AND Year(Date(transactions.timestamp)) = 2014 
       AND transactions.payment_status = 'Manually created' 
        OR payment_status = 'Completed' 
GROUP  BY Day(Date(timestamp))
```

Query looks fine right?

But then here are the results

[image: But here are the results]

How do I get rid of the extraneous entry for March? I tried using HAVING instead of WHERE but couldn't get the query to run.

Comment: Please reformat your code

Comment: Formatted remove down vote please !

Comment: Please share you table structure & some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think your Or condition should be in ().

```
SELECT Count(images.image_url)             AS num_images, 
       ( Day(Date(timestamp)) )            AS tday, 
       Month(Date(transactions.timestamp)) AS month, 
       transactions.sr_no 
FROM   bni_pixcapp_client_details AS transactions 
       INNER JOIN bni_pixcapp_image_urls AS images 
               ON images.sr_no = transactions.sr_no 
WHERE  Month(Date(transactions.timestamp)) = 4 
       AND Year(Date(transactions.timestamp)) = 2014 
       AND (
             transactions.payment_status = 'Manually created' 
           OR 
             payment_status = 'Completed' 
           )
GROUP  BY Day(Date(timestamp))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try your where clause like below
WHERE  (Month(Date(transactions.timestamp)) = 4 
       AND Year(Date(transactions.timestamp)) = 2014 )
       AND (transactions.payment_status = 'Manually created' 
        OR payment_status = 'Completed' )
```